Installation Errors with wheel in Google Colab (Could not build wheels for X, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects)
I am trying to run the Magic123 model in Google Colab, but I am encountering installation errors for several packages (raymarching, shencoder, freqencoder, and gridencoder). The installation fails during the execution of install.sh, with the following error for each package:
  Building wheel for freqencoder (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for freqencoder
  Running setup.py clean for freqencoder
Failed to build freqencoder
ERROR: Could not build wheels for freqencoder, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
Processing ./gridencoder
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: gridencoder
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Building wheel for gridencoder (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for gridencoder
  Running setup.py clean for gridencoder
Failed to build gridencoder
ERROR: Could not build wheels for gridencoder, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Here's what I've tried so far:

Ensured Wheel is installed and up to date.
Attempted to use different Python versions.

Recently, I found someone's work on Google Colab where they successfully installed Magic123 without any errors. However, when I try to run the compile notebook on my system, I encounter errors that they didn't. i would be very helpfull for your help since I am working on this errors for two weeks and have not found a solution.

you may try to run pip install with option -V (for verbose) (uppercase V)  to get more details in error message. But usually this type of error means it tries to compile some C/C++ code and it may need to install C/C++ compiler and some C/C++ libraries (with headers or source code in C/C++) - and this is not part of Python so you have to install it manually. On Google Colab (which probably use Linux Ubuntu) it needs to use command apt. But you have to get more details in error message to see what you have to install.
